# Fade effect makes other elements disappear - on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I've been working on a website, below link,

[www.production39.com](http://www.production39.com)

I have created some panels that will slide out when the right hand buttons are clicked (i.e. who we are, what we do, get in touch), then by clicking the back button, it will slide out of screen. I have set up a fade effect on the back button image onmouseover, and previewed it on the web so far so good. However, I've noticed an issue with the fading effect when I view it in Chrome, when I hover over the back button on the "who we are" and "what we do" panels, the content of the panel also disappear!

This doesn't happen with the "get in touch" panel though...

I have checked my code and I can't seem to find where the problem is... It would be lovely if someone can point me to the right direction?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Add related code and, if possible, a jsfiddle.

Comment: may be e.preventDefault() help.

Comment: I could not reproduce the bug. Looks fine here.